# How do I prevent my packaged functions from being listed with ls()?

Tags: r

I managed to build and install my R package and upon loading, all the functions in it are exported to the global environment and are visible from `ls()`. How can I prevent this so they behave like packages on CRAN and not pollute the global environment?

Comment: How did you manage to export all your functions in the global environment?

Comment: Visible from `ls()` or from `ls(pos=2)` or whichever `pos` the package is loaded at?

Comment: `ls()`, with the default pos argument.

Comment: did you source the r script with your functions before building your package? does this happen when you load the package in a fresh r session?

Comment: I grep'd for any `source` functions in the package and couldn't find any. This happens on a fresh R session.

Comment: Presumably you cleared the functions from the global environment before reloading the fresh session?  R will save the workspace and reload it, so if you're not actively clearing the functions starting in a fresh session won't necessarily remove them.

Comment: You were right, there was an .Rdata file and it was loading all the functions from the start. Deleting it, the functions in the package are kept separate.

Answer (score -1):

You can have them start with a leading dot `.`, if you simply do not want them to be listed when `ls()` is used with default parameters. However, that does not change their namespace or environment. You can still see them using `ls(all.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: have a look at point 3 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526467/what-does-the-dot-mean-in-r-personal-preference-naming-convention-or-more
took me some time to look up and find it - but has already been answered in SO ...

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but most likely [they simply should not](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports) export "all the functions".

Comment: @Roland I think even if you export all the functions, they don't show up in the global environment.

Comment: Surely the OP doesn't want a package where every function begins with a dot.  Hiding a function from `ls()` when called with its defaults does not solve the problem of having all the objects in the `globalenv()`

Comment: First - the functions supposed to be visible most probably won't start with a dot (.)
Second - the question still was: "How do I prevent my packaged functions from being listed with ls()". 
Third - if he already has his package build I am not sure if rewriting the whole thing via extensive use of "environment()" would be easier to achieve.

Comment: The goal is to make the package "behave like packages on CRAN and not pollute the global environment".  Hiding them is still pollution as could be seen with `ls(all.names=TRUE)`.  The functions need to be in the package's namespace, not the global environment.  Just like any function you're used to (`ls`, `cat`, `lm`, etc.).  When you type `ls()` you don't see those functions (and they don't begin with a dot), but they are still accessible because they are in an environment (other than .GlobalEnv) that is attached to the search path.