# what is the difference between these two statements in R?

Tags: r

I want to know the difference between

```
x.char = c("A", "B", "C")
```

and

```
x = c("A", "B", "C")
```

when should I use x.char instead of x?

thanks

Comment: I don't see why people are downvoting this. It's a valid question to ask, and a common misunderstanding among people coming from other languages.

Comment: Related: [What does the dot mean in R – personal preference, naming convention or more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526467/what-does-the-dot-mean-in-r-personal-preference-naming-convention-or-more)

Comment: ...and perhaps: [The State of Naming Conventions in R](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Baaaath.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're coming from programming languages where the dot (`.`) means something. Eg in C++, C# and Java, `x.foo` means the `foo` member of the `x` class.

In R, `.` is not anything special. It's just another character that you can use in a variable name. In your example, `x.char` is a variable, and `x` is another variable. There's no difference between the two statements, except that they refer to different variables.

Comment: thank you so much! I have studied javascript before haha

Comment: `.` is actually important in the naming of functions (as you know). But that's probably a bit advanced for this question.

Comment: @RichScriven that's more of a defect with S3 than anything. Eg `as.data.frame.foo` could be the `as` method for `data.frame.foo`, the `as.data` method for `frame.foo`, the `as.data.frame` method for `foo`, or just a plain old variable.