# Convention for cell-local variables in R markdown

Tags: r, naming-conventions, r-markdown, unused-variables

I often have variables in cells that I do not need again. Say a loop index or just an intermediate result. These build up in the list of variables in RStudio, and it does not make it easier to work with.

Therefore I would like to mark those “cell local” variables such that they are not used in other cells. I am using underscores instead of dots to separate words in identifiers, sticking with Hadley Wickam's guideline.

One convention that I have seen is prefixing with a dot. Does that make sense in this case? Or rather an underscore, like in Python?

Comment: Might clear things up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526926/1777111 Starting a variable or function name with an underscore does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume  you mean "chunk local."  There is nothing automatic I know of, but if you a convention like a leading `.`, you can periodically run something like

```
 rm(grep("^.", ls(), value=TRUE))
```

in a chunk