# Why the code only works with numbers and not letters?

Tags: r

I have to use the code bellow but I don't completely understand how it works. Why it won't work if I change du.4 by du.f and then use the f when calling the function? For some reason it only works with numbers and I do not undarstand why.

This is the error that it is giving in the case of du.f

```
Error in paste("Meth1=", nr, ".ps", sep = "") : object 'f' not found
```

```
du.4 <- function(u,v,a){(exp(a)*(-1+exp(a*v)))/(-exp(a)+exp(a+a*u)-exp(a*(u+v))+exp(a+a*v))}

plotmeth1 <- function(data1,data2,alpha,nr) {
     psfile <-paste("Meth1=",nr,".ps",sep="")
     diffmethod <-paste("du.",nr,sep="")
     title=paste("Family",nr)
     alphavalue <-paste("alpha=",round(alpha,digits=3),sep="")
     #message=c("no message")
     postscript(psfile)
     data3<-sort(eval(call(diffmethod,data1,data2,alpha)))
     diffdata <-data3[!is.na(data3)]
     #if(length(data3)>length(diffdata))
     #{message=paste("Family ",nr,"contains NA!")}
     tq <-((1:length(diffdata))/(length(diffdata)+1))
     plot(diffdata,tq,main=title,xlab="C1[F(x),G(y)]",ylab="U(0,1)",type="l")
     legend(0.6,0.3,c(alphavalue))
     abline(0,1)
     #dev.off()
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "using f when calling its function"? Does that mean that you are trying to evaluate `function(data1,data2,alpha,f)` without actually defining `f`? If so, why should that work? If you define a function called `du.f` then you can't refer to that function as `f`. If that isn't the issue, please provide a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R.

Comment: I mean that if I define it like `du.f ` then `plotmeth1 (data1, data2, alpha, f) ` is not working. data1, data2 and aplha can be anything.

Comment: If you define a function called `du.f` then it is called `du.f`, not `f`. If you want to refer to the function as `f`, don't use another name when defining it. Just use `f`. A dot in an R function definition is typically just another character. You wouldn't expect to be able to refer to `durf` as `f`. The case with `du.f` is no different. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7526467/4996248) about the dot in R identifiers.

Comment: Gabriela, are you coming to R from python or another programming language? Do you have an object in the environment named `du`? In other languages that might mean something, but in R typically not. Since you had `du.4` before, were you calling that function as anything other than `du.4`? If you define `du.4`, "of course" `4` by itself works, it is always good in R and most languages as it is a literal number.

Comment: Actually that is the only definition I have, and what I do not know is why when I call it `du.4` then it works just by `4` but when I call it `du.f` it does not work by `f`. And how could I do so it would work if I define it by `du.f`. And yes, I haven't worked with R a lot.

Comment: But if I do it like that it gives me exactly the plot I need. So I think that the code works in that case.

Comment: I understand the question now. The difference that you are observing is traceable to the fact that `paste` will coerce numbers to strings, but it won't coerce undefined objects into strings. See my answer as edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, a dot is used as just another character in identifiers. It is often used for clarity but doesn't have a formal function in defining the part after the dot as being in a name-space given by the part of the identifier before the dot. In something like `du.f` you can't refer to the function by `f` alone, even if your computation is inside of an environment named `du`. You can of course define a function named `du.4` and then use `4` all by itself, but when you do so you are using the number `4` as just a number and not as a reference to the function. For example, if

```
du.4 <- function(u,v,a){(exp(a)*(-1+exp(a*v)))/(-exp(a)+exp(a+a*u)-exp(a*(u+v))+exp(a+a*v))}
```

Then `du.4(1,2,3)` evaluates to `21.08554` but attempting to use `4(1,2,3)` throws the error

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

In the case of your code, you are using `paste` to assemble the function name as a string to be passed to `eval`. It makes sense to paste the literal number 4 onto the string `'du.'` (since the paste will convert `4` to the string `'4'`) but it doesn't make sense to paste an undefined `f` onto `'du.'`. It does, however, make sense to paste the literal string `'f'` onto `'du.'`, so that the function call `plotmeth1 (data1, data2, alpha, 'f')` will work even though `plotmeth1 (data1, data2, alpha, f)` will fail.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7526467/4996248) for more about the use of the dot in R identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I see it now.